# Worklight 6.1 Direct Update stuck in 99%

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm trying to use Direct Update on my WL 6.1 project but nothing I do works.

I tried Eclipse Kepler and Juno.
I tried several WL 6.1 versions (patches) and nothing.

Here is the symptoms - and there is no error log or anything similar. The only thing that I see is the downloading messaging stucked in 99%.

I'm suspecting of a configuration problem because one member of my team CAN do the Direct Update. Both of us are using a Mac for development and the same server.

Another relevant information I have is that I can't use either, the direct update when I'm in the development environment, I mean, in my Eclipse WL Studio plugin/server. As soon as the App starts, it shows the message about the new update, but as soon as I click update, i receive the message: Updated Failed: Failed  processing  application update file.

(I'm using an iOS Environment).

Maybe, one information that may help is: I'm behind a reverse proxy to access the WL Server. As soon as I try to connect to WL, using WL.Client.Connect or calling an Adapter, the server tell me that there is an update. But after 99% completion, it's stucks.

I really don't know which kind of information I can post in here, so, please, ask whatever you want and I'll update the post.

Please help.

[UPDATED]

Here is the log of the device when it tries to update the App. This log is just after WL.Client.Connect:

```
<Warning>: [INFO] [wl.client] WL.Client.connect onConnectSuccess ENTERING
<Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient connect success
<Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'PUSHTest' access to protected services is denied.
<Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '102.169922' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
<Warning>: [ERROR] [NONE] Update checksum is 3449626805
<Warning>: [ERROR] [NONE] In Progress checksum is 0
<Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://.../apps/services/api/PUSHTest/iphone/setup]
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 0 to 8388608
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['WebResourcesDownloader'] took '18.403076' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] response [https://.../apps/services/api/PUSHTest/iphone/setup] success: 
<Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] defaultOptions:onSuccess
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 0
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 15891
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 15891
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1390960
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1455656
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1466344 to 9854952
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1466344
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485118 to 9873726
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485118
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485118

<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485118
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485118
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485358 to 9873966
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485358
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485358
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485358
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485358
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485362 to 9873970
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485362 to 9873970
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485362 to 9873970
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
...
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Requesting bytes starting from 1485362 to 9873970
<Warning>: Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
<Warning>: Start downloading update file.
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
<Warning>: Length of update file is: 1485362
...
```

And then keep going with this same log.

Comment: What happens if you use a new workspace and import the project to it and try again?

Comment: I tried a new project, a new Eclipse installation, several WL versions, Eclipse Juno and Kepler and all of then has the same effect.

Comment: Weird. Maybe the problem is at the other end. Tried restarting the device? reset the iOS Simulator?

Comment: Same thing. Could be something related to a OS X Configuration ? I have Java 1.7 and 1.8 installed in my machine, but Eclipse is pointing to 1.7. Is there any "Build All Script" that could be messed?

Comment: Is this setup you've mentioned the same at your co-worker?

Comment: did you add the new iFix to your eclipse env?? i had the same problem when i deployed the ifix on eclipse but did not apply it to the server.

Comment: No, I didn't apply any fix, neither to the server nor to Eclipse.

Comment: I just re done everything in another computer and the symptoms was the same. I'm going to create a new Project and try again. I'll let you know.

Comment: Back to the original computer. New workspace.
Create a new project. Re-code line by line, doing the tests.
Nothing. I'm stuck in the same problem.
Anyone?

Comment: i would check the versions in case.... when you create your ipa file. unpack it and check payload --> <appname.app> --> worklight.plist look at platform version.... then check the server lib(worklight-jee-library.jar) that your server.xml points to open wlPlatformVersion.properties and see the buildNumber in there

Comment: Hi tik27. I got the platform version:
    <key>platformVersion</key>
    <string>6.1.0.01.20140804-0726</string>
But didn't understand the 2nd part: wlPlatformVersion.
I can get my server version:
    Server version: 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630

Comment: Hi I did another test: create a new Eclipse (Juno), installed the WL 6.1 with the same release as of the server and still nothing.
Must be something in my OS X or Java configuration.

Comment: well it seems your server and eclipse environments are 1 fixpack apart.  I would add fixpack 1 to the server.

Comment: I think I finally fix this. I found a WL version exactly the same as the server. I'll do some more tests and update the post.

Comment: Best to write an answer when this is verified.

Comment: I suspect there would be a JavaScript coding mistake (syntax most probably), try JS-Lint on the code.

Comment: Any success to share with us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finished the test and the problem was the WL version. I put the same version of the server and did one, only one fix, and the problem was gone.
The fix was because the server version of Worklight didn't support iOS 7.